# Model Based Testing Strategies

Tags: testing, integration-testing, mbt

What strategies have you used with Model Based Testing?

- Do you use it exclusively for
  integration testing, or branch it
  out to other areas
  (unit/functional/system/spec verification)?
- Do you build focused "sealed" models  or do you evolve complex onibus models over time?
- When in the product cycle do you invest in creating MBTs?
- What sort of base test libraries do you exclusively create for  MBTs?
- What difference do you make in your functional base test libraries to better support MBTs?
  ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 14):

[There are several essays worth reading on this. Stack Overflow won't let me post more than one, so I've aggregated them in a blog post, linked at the end of this answer.]

First, a quick note on terms. I tend to use James Bach’s definition of Testing as “Questioning a product in order to evaluate it”. All test rely on /mental/ models of the application under test. The term Model-Based Testing though is typically used to describe programming a model which can be explored via automation. For example, one might specify a number of states that an application can be in, various paths between those states, and certain assertions about what should occur in on the transition between those states. Then one can have scripts execute semi-random permutations of transitions within the state model, logging potentially interesting results.

There are real costs here: building a useful model, creating algorithms for exploring it, logging systems that allow one to weed through for interesting failures, etc. Whether or not the costs are reasonable has a lot to do with *what are the questions you want to answer?* In general, start with “What do I want to know? And how can I best learn about it?” rather than looking for a use for an interesting technique.

All that said, some excellent testers have gotten a lot of mileage out of automated model-based tests. Sometimes we have important questions about the application under test that are best explored by automated, high-volume semi-randomized tests. Harry Robinson (one of the leading theorists and proponents of model-based testing) describes one very colorful example where he discovered many interesting bugs in Google driving directions using a model-based test (written with ruby’s Watir library). [1](http://testingjeff.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/question-about-model-based-testing/)

Robinson has used MBT successfully at companies including Bell Labs, Microsoft, and Google, and has a number of helpful essays.[2]

Ben Simo (another great testing thinker and writer) has also written quite a bit worth reading on model-based testing.[3]

Finally, a few cautions: To make good use of a strategy, one needs to explore both its strengths and its weaknesses. Toward that end, James Bach has an excellent talk on the limits and challenges of Model-Based Testing. This blog post of Bach’s links to his hour long talk (and associated slides).[4]

I’ll end with a note about what Boris Beizer calls the Pesticide Paradox: “Every method you use to prevent or find bugs leaves a residue of subtler bugs against which those methods are ineffective.” Scripted tests (whether executed by a computer or a person) are particularly vulnerable to the pesticide paradox, tending to find less and less useful information each time the same script is executed. Folks sometimes turn to model-based testing thinking that it gets around the pesticide problem. In some contexts model-based testing may well find a much larger set of bugs than a given set of scripted tests…but one should remember that it is still fundamentally limited by the Pesticide Paradox. Remembering its limits — and starting with questions MBT addresses well — it has the potential to be a very powerful testing strategy.

Links to all essays mentioned above can be found here: http://testingjeff.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/question-about-model-based-testing/

Answer (score 1):

We haven't done any/much I&T and use unit testing almost exclusively, seasoned with a bit of system testing. But our focus is clearly on unit testing. I'm pretty strict on the APIs we build/provide, so the assumption is, if it works by itself, it will work in conjunction and there hasn't been much wrong in it yet.

Our models are focused on a single purpose/module with as little dependencies as possible.

The focus is always to start as early as possible (TDD-kinda), but unfortunately we don't always get to it. The problem is, you always have to sell it to management and then it's hard because while testing improves stability (overall QA), the people from the outside (outside of tech) can't really relate to what that means until something bad happened.

Since we use PHP, we employ PHPUnit for the unit tests. All in all, we do CI with various different tools. :)

Answer (score 1):

Harry Robinson, an author of MBT-books and worked a lot with it for example at Google and Microsoft have this site with some great info and whitepapers.

http://www.geocities.com/model_based_testing/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to try by yourself a Model based testing tool. It's the best way for know if the model based testing is adapted in your context. And what sort of strategies is the good one.

I advise you the "MaTeLo" tool of All4Tec (www.all4tec.net)

"MaTeLo is a test cases generator for black box functional and system testing. Conformed to the Model Based Testing approach, MaTeLo uses Markov chains for modeling the test. This statistic addin allows products validation in a Systematic way. The efficiency is achieved by a reduction of the human resources needed, an increase of the model reuse and by the enhancement of the test strategy relevance (due to the reliability target). MaTeLo is independent and user-friendly, offers to the validation activities to pass from test scripting to real test engineering and to focus on the real added value of testing: the test plans"

You can ask an evaluation licence and try by yourself.

You can find some exemples here : http://www.all4tec.net/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorials